# django drf serializer with a many-to-many model (with extra data)

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

NOTE:  this isn't really about getting Django's intermediate model for many-to-many relationship with extra fields to work.  this is about how to use Django Rest Framework's Serializers.ModelSerializer with an intermediate model.
I have these models (and more):

```
class Method(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    descripton = models.TextField(null=False)

class Version(models.Model):
    version_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cmd_line_script = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    SOP = models.TextField(null=False)
    FK_method = models.ForeignKey(Method, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('version_number', 'FK_method')

class Instrument(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    asset_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    checksum_string = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    FK_instr_type = models.ForeignKey(InstrType, related_name='installations', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Instr_Version = models.ManyToManyField(
                        Version, 
                        through='Instr_Version', 
                        related_name = 'Instr_Version',
                    )

class Instr_Version(models.Model):
    FK_version = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    FK_instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    validating_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('FK_version', 'FK_instrument')
```

and they're fine.  I'm trying to use the `[Django-Rest-Framework serializers][1]` to serialize through the Instr_Version table so an api can retrieve a json representation of all the versions (and their FK_method data, via a MethodSerializer) that are listed as valid for that instrument.
I have these serializers so far (and a couple more for InstrType, UserProfile, etc)

```
class MethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Method
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'version_set')

class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    method = MethodSerializer(read_only=True)
    #Instr_Version = Instr_VersionSerializer(source='Instr_Version_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = ('id', 'method', 'version_number', 'cmd_line_script', 'SOP')

class Instr_to_VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(source='FK_version_id', read_only=True, many=False)
    validator = UserProfileSerializer(source='validating_user', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instr_Version
        fields = ('id', 'version', 'validator', 'timestamp')


class InstrumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instr_type = InstrTypeSerializer(source='FK_instr_type', read_only=True)
    Validated_Versions = Instr_to_VersionSerializer(source='Instr_Version', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instrument
        fields = ('id', 'asset_number', 'serial_number', 'name', 'checksum_string', 'instr_type', 'Validated_Versions')
```

The closest I've gotten is that a GET like: "api/getInstrument/?asset_number=1234"
results in:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "asset_number": "1234",
    "serial_number": "1234",
    "name": "Instrument1",
    "checksum_string": "0123456789ABCDEF0123",
    "instr_type": {
        "id": 70,
        "make": "Make1",
        "model": "Model1",
        "service_email": "model1@company.com",
        "service_website": "www.model1.com"
    },
    "Validated_Versions": [{
        "id": 9
    }, {
        "id": 10
    }, {
        "id": 12
    }]
}
```

Which is pretty good, but the validated_versions array should have a lot more data than just an 'id'.

I tried adding/removing the `id` from the fields list in `Instr_to_VersionSerializer` and `VersionSerializer` for experiment's sake.  evidence says that the `id` in the fields list within `Instr_to_VersionSerializer` is actually printing the `FK_version_id` on the `Instr_Version` model (or the PK on the Version model), not the PK of `Instr_Version` like I had expected.  This made me think that DJR was 'automatically' seeing through the many-to-many, straight to the `Version` model, so I tried changing `Instr_to_VersionSerializer` to:

```
class Instr_to_VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #version = VersionSerializer(source='FK_version_id', read_only=True, many=False)
    validator = UserProfileSerializer(source='validating_user', read_only=True)
    #method = MethodSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instr_Version
        fields = ('id', 'version_number', 'cmd_line_script', 'SOP', 'validator', 'timestamp')
```

Which would leave the VersionSerializer out of it entirely, but I get a `Field name`version_number`is not valid for model`Instr_Version`.` error, so I'm not sure what's going on.

One final attempt myself was to change the `source` for the `version = VersionSerializer` to `versions`, which is the reverse relationship.  this seemed illogical, but I'm at that point where I'm trying anything.  result was: an error that `version_number` was not a valid field, which told me I was finally getting to the `VersionSerializer`, so I commented out most of the fields in `VersionSerializer` just to see what was happening, but this only led to: 
`"Validated_Versions":[{"id":9,"version":{}},{"id":10,"version":{}},{"id":12,"version":{}}]`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `related_name` for the relationship between `Instruments` and `Instr_Version` was causing the problem.  I updated the model to:

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    asset_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    checksum_string = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    FK_instr_type = models.ForeignKey(InstrType, related_name='installations', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    VersionsFromInstrument = models.ManyToManyField(
                        Version, 
                        through='Instr_Version', 
                        related_name = 'InstrumentsFromVersion',
                    )
```

(Note the new related_name on the last attribute, and that I changed the attribute name), and the serializers accordingly and this is working better.  note I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` with `manage.py` after updating this model, then it's working.  New result is:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "asset_number": "1234",
    "serial_number": "1234",
    "name": "Instrument1",
    "checksum_string": "0123456789ABCDEF0123",
    "instr_type": {
        "id": 70,
        "make": "Make1",
        "model": "Model1",
        "service_email": "model1@company.com",
        "service_website": "www.model1.com"
    },
    "Validated_Versions": [{
        "id": 9,
        "method": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Method1",
            "description": "method one description",
            "version_set": [11, 9]
        },
        "version_name": "123",
        "cmd_line_script": "script",
        "SOP": "SOP"
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "method": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Method2",
            "description": "method two description",
            "version_set": [12, 10]
        },
        "version_name": "123",
        "cmd_line_script": "script",
        "SOP": "SOP"
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "method": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Method2",
            "description": "method two description",
            "version_set": [12, 10]
        },
        "version_name": "456",
        "cmd_line_script": "script",
        "SOP": "SOP"
    }]
}
```

in case it's helpful to others in the future, here's my updated Serilaizers to correlate with the changes to model:

```
class MethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='descripton')
    class Meta:
        model = Method
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'version_set')

class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    method = MethodSerializer(read_only=True)
    #Instr_Version = Instr_VersionSerializer(source='Instr_Version_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = ('id', 'method')#, 'version_number', 'cmd_line_script', 'SOP')

class Instr_to_VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(source='FK_version', read_only=True, many=True)
    validator = UserProfileSerializer(source='validating_user', read_only=True)
    version_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='version_number')
    cmd_line_script = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    SOP = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    method = MethodSerializer(source='FK_method',read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instr_Version
        fields = ('id', 'version', 'validator', 'timestamp', 'method', 'version_name', 'cmd_line_script', 'SOP')


class InstrumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instr_type = InstrTypeSerializer(source='FK_instr_type', read_only=True)
    Validated_Versions = Instr_to_VersionSerializer(source='VersionsFromInstrument', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instrument
        fields = ('id', 'asset_number', 'serial_number', 'name', 'checksum_string', 'instr_type', 'Validated_Versions')
```

Especially note the `Validated_Versions =` line of the `InstrumentSerializer`

One thing I'm missing is that I really want to see the `validating_user` and `timestamp` fields on the `Instr_Version` model in the result, so I still have to work on that.  I'll update when I get it working.